# Why does System.Numerics.Complex use doubles instead of decimals?

Tags: c#-4.0, floating-point

I've been working with `System.Numerics.Complex` recently, and I've started to notice the typical floating-point "drift" where the value stored gets calculated a tenth of a millionth off or something like that, which is well-known and common with the `float` type and even the `double` type. I looked into the Complex struct, and sure enough, it used `double` variables. Why does it use `double` values to store its data and not `decimal` values, which are designed to prevent this? How do I work around this?

Comment: `decimal` is not designed to prevent drift. It is designed to represent exactly decimal values. The fact that it uses 128 bits may make the drift more acceptable to you, but the extra precision comes at such a performance cost that the designers considered that the majority would be better served by a `Complex` type based on `double`.

Comment: Nature doesn't count with 10 fingers, only humans do.

Comment: .NET's decimal also has a rather small exponent (in Decimal, it is called "scale") range, more or less between 10^28 and 10^-28. Double has a much larger range.

Comment: @HansPassant: Nature doesn't count with 2 fingers either. Computers do, though. <g>

Comment: Sure, the air-speed of a laden swallow can only be expressed exactly with a limited number of digits with a pythonic base.

Comment: An African or a European swallow?

Comment: Swallows always remind me of that Monty Python skit...

Comment: Interesting. What is the best way to deal with the "drift" that `double` values sometimes have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. `double`s are several orders of magnitude faster, as operations are done at the hardware level
2. base-2 floats can actually be *more* accurate for large computations, as there is less "wobble" when shifting up and down exponents: 1 bit of precision is less than 1 decimal digit. Moreover, base-2 can use an implicit leading bit, which means they can represent more numbers than other bases.
3. complex numbers are typically used for scientific/engineering applications, where small relative errors of approx 10<sup>-16</sup> are outweighed by other sources of error (e.g. due to measurement or the model).
4. decimals on the other hand are typically used for "accounting" type operations, where round-off error is typically negligible (i.e. addition of small numbers, multiplication by integers, etc.)